# Preserving polygon boundaries when vectorizing raster according to polygon vector?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, vector, clip, vectorization

I have a raster which I clip by some polygons and then convert to polygon. I would like to obtain the same number of polygons in both my vector files.

The problem is that some areas in the vector clipper are separated by a line (i.e. adjacent polygons) are now together (as I would expect). When I perform the vectorization of my cropped raster, I get less polygons than what I want (for the reason I just mentioned).

Is there a way to preserve polygon boundaries when performing raster to vector transformation according to a given polygon vector (that is, my clipper file)?

I use ArcGIS, QGIS, GRASSgis, python, MATLAB/octave.

[image]

Comment: You can do this manually in QGIS via _Edit_ > _Reshape Features_. But hopefully others can provide a detailed answer with using transformational tools that would do this automatically (and much more accurately).

Comment: Thank you, but that's what I am looking for, an automatic method. Anyway, your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you crop again with your clipper after vectorizing? That way any combined polygons derived from your raster layer will match your original clipping layer. If you don't want to add an extra step you can vectorize the entire raster layer then clip to vector layer (though this could take more computation time).

Any other option I can think of would involve changing raster values, which could get messy.

Comment: Some areas still are not correctly cropped, I will try something different (maybe an intersection?)

Comment: this is more or less what I actually was looking for, but still, it turns out a clip does not separate polygons which are adjacent, letting to polygons that are merged when in the clipper are separated by a line (that is adjacent polygons)